# How do I check in PowerShell if a service has read access to a certain folder?

Tags: powershell, file-permissions, access-control

So far, I know to do the following:

1. Determine the service logon account - `(Get-WmiObject -Query "SELECT StartName FROM win32_service where name = 'mssqlserver'").StartName`
2. Get accounts that have read access to the folder - `accesschk -q -d $env:TEMP`

But this leads me nowhere:

```
PS C:\> (Get-WmiObject -Query "SELECT StartName FROM win32_service where name = 'mssqlserver'").StartName
LocalSystem
PS C:\> accesschk -q -d $env:TEMP
c:\Users\MKHARI~1\AppData\Local\Temp
  RW NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
  RW BUILTIN\Administrators
  RW DAYFORCE\mkharitonov
PS C:\> accesschk LocalSystem -q -d $env:TEMP

Accesschk v5.2 - Reports effective permissions for securable objects
Copyright (C) 2006-2014 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

  Error looking up account: LocalSystem:
  The operation completed successfully.
PS C:\> accesschk "DAYFORCE\mkharitonov" -q -d $env:TEMP
RW c:\Users\MKHARI~1\AppData\Local\Temp
PS C:\>
```

The AccessChk does not seem to recognize `LocalSystem`. Also, if I run it with an account belonging to the `BUILTIN\Administrators`, it does not seem to acknowledge the access.

Does it mean AccessChk is not suitable for this or am I using it wrong? Is there a way to do it at all without actually trying to access the folder under the account in question?

When PowerShell is running not as administrator:

```
PS C:\> $service = Get-WmiObject -EnableAllPrivileges Win32_Service | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "MSSQLSERVER"}
PS C:\> '{0:x}' -f $service.GetSecurityDescriptor().ReturnValue
80070522
PS C:\>
```

Which corresponds to **A required privilege is not held by the client**. The command works OK when the PowerShell is running as administrator. Ideally, I would like a solution that does not require elevation.

Comment: Can you check with this (as localsystem uses the token of nt authority\System) : accesschk.exe system -q -d $env:temp

Comment: That looks good, it outputs **RW c:\Users\MKHARI~1\AppData\Local\Temp**.  However, `(Get-WmiObject -Query "SELECT StartName FROM win32_service where name = 'mssqlserver'").StartName` returns **LocalSystem**, not **System**. If this is a special case - I can map LocalSystem to System in my script. But I am worried that there are maybe more cases when WMI returns something that needs to be mapped to something else before calling accesschk.exe. Any ideas?

Comment: I have updated the solution as answer,Can you check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

localsystem uses the token of nt authority\System, so this command line will work (you will need to map the localsystem to system in code):

```
accesschk.exe system -q -d $env:temp
```

I have created a snippet to fetch the proper name and pass it to accesschk (tested in PowerShell v5 and requires elevated access):

```
$service = Get-WmiObject -EnableAllPrivileges Win32_Service | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "wlidsvc"}
 $desc = (($service.GetSecurityDescriptor()).Descriptor).owner
 $desc.Domain + "\"+$desc.name | %{.\accesschk.exe $_ -q -d $env:temp}
```

$desc.Domain + "\"+$desc.name will return NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM instead of localsystem

PS: The script can be optimized

Comment: Please, see **EDIT 1**

Comment: Please, include the accesschk.exe command line in the answer with the need to map LocalSystem to system. This is good enough for me to mark it as answer. If you have a way to get the canonical user name without elevation - that would be an extra bonus for me.

Comment: @mark I have added the accesschk commandline as you suggested

Answer (score 0):

```
$account = 'whatever you like'
$acl = Get-Acl 'folder'
$acl.access | where { $_.IdentityReference -like "*$account*"}).FileSystemRights
```

I am not sure this will work with PowerShell v.2, but it will work for PowerShell v.3 and later.

Comment: How does it help me exactly? In my example the ACL returns three subjects -   `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`, `BUILTIN\Administrators` and  `DAYFORCE\mkharitonov`. None of them matches `LocalSystem` and yet the latter does have access, being a local administrator.

Comment: `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` is `LocalSystem`

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684190(v=vs.85).aspx @mark

Comment: `BUILTIN\Administrators` is a group. So any account in this group has access. But the simple string matching will not reveal it.

Comment: what does that supposed to mean

Comment: `$_.IdentityReference -like "*$account*"` is a string matching, isn't it?